# Tomcat interfering with other website in public_html

Tags: apache, tomcat, drupal, fedora, public-html

I am trying to install Islandora on an server running both drupal and Fedora.  Fedora runs on Tomcat, which seems to take of the public_html directory.

I believe it is related to this link:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/530321/Tomcat/SOLVED-Tomcat-subdirectory-mapping-WWW

Fedora is running fine, but when I try to run Drupal I get a error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /drupal

type Status report

message /drupal

description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.56
```

Guidance would be great.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Great Resource from JVMHost: [www.jvmhost.com/articles/mapping-apache-tomcat-other-application-servers](http://www.jvmhost.com/articles/mapping-apache-tomcat-other-application-servers)

Comment: Another Resource from JVMHost: [https://uc1.nodecluster.net/jcp/site/page/view/mappings-howto](https://uc1.nodecluster.net/jcp/site/page/view/mappings-howto) - although I am still trying to get this working on my server.